# Display Success/Failure response for each operation

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to display a response message for each operation on my page.
When updating the user and the operation is successful, i want to display a closable message:

"User successfully updated" if operation is not successful i would like to display the error or exception i got on server side.

I've tried using the examples here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

Few issues:

1. The messages are not closable
2. All the messages were displayed at the same time, i couldn't attache a key to a message, even though i used different "for" attribute for each message.

I'm working with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:form id="ni">
        <p:messages for="Message1" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true" globalOnly="false" />
        <p:messages for="Message2" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true" globalOnly="false" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{normalIdentifiers}" var="i"
            styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            columnClasses="order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,
                    order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">User Id</f:facet>#{i.userId}</h:column>
          .. 
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="niUpdate#{i.id}" value="Update"
                    onclick="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.show()" type="button" />
                <p:confirmDialog id="niUpdateConfirmDialog#{i.id}"
                    message="Are you sure you want to Update this Identifier?"
                    showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop" header="Update Identifier"
                    severity="alert" widgetVar="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}"
                    modal="true">
                    <h:commandButton value="Yes"
                        oncomplete="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.hide()"
                        actionListener="#{identifierManager.updateNormalIdentifier(i)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton value="No"
                        onclick="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="niDelete#{i.id}" value="Delete"
                    onclick="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.show()" type="button" />
                <p:confirmDialog id="niDeleteConfirmDialog#{i.id}"
                    message="Are you sure you want to delete this Identifier?"
                    showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop" header="Delete"
                    severity="alert" widgetVar="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}"
                    modal="true">
                    <h:commandButton value="Yes"
                        oncomplete="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.hide()"
                        actionListener="#{identifierManager.removeNormalIdentifier(i)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton value="No"
                        onclick="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="insert"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Insert" id="niInsert#{i.id}"
                    onclick="niInsert#{i.id}.show()" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:dialog id="niConfirmDialogInsert#{i.id}"
                    header="Insert New Identifier" widgetVar="niInsert#{i.id}"
                    height="300" width="300">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="vertical-align:top;  ">
                     ..                   
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton id="niConfirmInsert#{i.id}" value="OK"
                        oncomplete="niInsert#{i.id}.hide()"
                        action="#{identifierManager.insertNormalIdentifier(i.userId)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton id="niDeclineInsert#{i.id}" value="Cancel"
                        onclick="niInsert#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:dialog>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "identifierManager")
@SessionScoped
public class IdentifiersManager {
  ...
    public void updateNormalIdentifier(NormalIdentifier normalIdentifier) {
        ...
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Message1", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Update", "Update"));
    }

    public void insertNormalIdentifier(Integer userId) {
        try {
            ..
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Message2", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Insert", "Insert"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
        }
    }


    public void removeNormalIdentifier(NormalIdentifier identifier) {
      ...
    }
}
```

---

I've used "p:message", but now, how can i hide the messages after few seconds. Also how can i clear all messages when page reloads.
Here is the updated code:

xhtml page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:form id="ni">

        <h:inputHidden id="txt" value="1" />
        <p:message for="txt" />

        <h:dataTable value="#{normalIdentifiers}" var="i"
            styleClass="order-table" headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            columnClasses="order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,
                    order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column,order-column">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">User Id</f:facet>#{i.userId}</h:column>
          .. 
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="niUpdate#{i.id}" value="Update"
                    onclick="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.show()" type="button" />
                <p:confirmDialog id="niUpdateConfirmDialog#{i.id}"
                    message="Are you sure you want to Update this Identifier?"
                    showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop" header="Update Identifier"
                    severity="alert" widgetVar="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}"
                    modal="true">
                    <h:commandButton value="Yes"
                        oncomplete="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.hide()"
                        actionListener="#{identifierManager.updateNormalIdentifier(i)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton value="No"
                        onclick="niConfirmationUpdate#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="niDelete#{i.id}" value="Delete"
                    onclick="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.show()" type="button" />
                <p:confirmDialog id="niDeleteConfirmDialog#{i.id}"
                    message="Are you sure you want to delete this Identifier?"
                    showEffect="drop" hideEffect="drop" header="Delete"
                    severity="alert" widgetVar="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}"
                    modal="true">
                    <h:commandButton value="Yes"
                        oncomplete="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.hide()"
                        actionListener="#{identifierManager.removeNormalIdentifier(i)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton value="No"
                        onclick="niConfirmationDelete#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="insert"></f:facet>
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Insert" id="niInsert#{i.id}"
                    onclick="niInsert#{i.id}.show()" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:dialog id="niConfirmDialogInsert#{i.id}"
                    header="Insert New Identifier" widgetVar="niInsert#{i.id}"
                    height="300" width="300">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="vertical-align:top;  ">
                     ..                   
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton id="niConfirmInsert#{i.id}" value="OK"
                        oncomplete="niInsert#{i.id}.hide()"
                        action="#{identifierManager.insertNormalIdentifier(i.userId)}"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px;margin: 10px 5px;" />
                    <h:commandButton id="niDeclineInsert#{i.id}" value="Cancel"
                        onclick="niInsert#{i.id}.hide()" type="button"
                        style="width: 80px;height: 24px" />
                </p:dialog>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "identifierManager")
@SessionScoped
public class IdentifiersManager {
  ...
    public void updateNormalIdentifier(NormalIdentifier normalIdentifier) {
        ...
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("normalUserIdentifiers:ni:txt", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "PrimeFaces Rocks."));

    }

    public void insertNormalIdentifier(Integer userId) {
        try {
            ..
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
        }
    }


    public void removeNormalIdentifier(NormalIdentifier identifier) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use some notification mechanism at each stage, which can be universal, for sending different types of notification. Cometd comes in mind, with which you can send messages to client at each step.

Comment: You try to use the 5.2.x showcase examples on 3.1.1... Not good

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<p:message` instead of `<p:messages` if you want to use the `for` attribute.

Unfortunately the `closable` attribute is only available on the `<p:messages` element on more recent versions.

For more information see : http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_1.pdf